# Android app showing offline map of some place say x

Tags: android, maps, offlineapps

how to make an Andrid app , which will show  some place x 's map offline , map data will be fetched from internet and will be part of resource for app .
i will have maps rectanguler area (diagonal lat long co-ordinates) , i will somehow download tiles (map images ) given some zoom levels ,place them in app resources ,when the app runs , it should show those areas like google map shows , but only downloaded area .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Nutiteq maps SDK http://developer.nutiteq.com ? It has exactly these features.

Comment: following how to use in my app , i am not able to get any result .

Comment: i followed the guide to use this in my app , not succeded .

Comment: What was your problem exactly?

Comment: @ jaakL  this link  https://developer.nutiteq.com/getting-started/android ,does use of internet ,i need to use maptiles created and stored in app ,it does not guide ,how to do that .

Comment: Yes, getting started is with online maps. You can find following pages with offline options: https://developer.nutiteq.com/guides/offline-maps - with OSM offline maps, or https://developer.nutiteq.com/guides/data-sources - more custom offline map sources